# How can I search and sort faunadb by the created timestamp

Tags: faunadb

I want to retrieve the results from the quizzes and return the newest ones first, I see there is  a ts - timestamp field which records the created time. Please see my query below.

```
await client.query(
    q.Map(
        q.Paginate(
    q.Match(q.Index("all_school_queries")),

            {size:1000}
        ),
        q.Lambda(
            "school_query",
            q.Get(q.Var("school_query"))
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your current query uses an 'all_school_queries' index which I assume just returns references. That means it will have **ref** in values or nothing at all in values (since ref will be the default return value). So currently your index probably looks like this:

CreateIndex(
{
name: "all_school_queries",
source: Collection('')
}
)
To sort this index, we need to add values (currently it's sorted by reference). So to get an (almost) equivalent index we can write this.

```
CreateIndex({
      name: "all_school_queries",
      source: Collection('<yourcollection>'),
      values:   values: [
         {
           field: ["ref"]
         }
      ]
    })
```

Values determine:

- What the index will return
- In what order that index will return these values (again by ref here)
- What range queries we can write on this index, in the above case we can write a range query on ref (which is useless of course).

We can however add as many values as we want so let's make sure we can sort by ts

```
CreateIndex({
  name: "all_school_queries",
  source: Collection('<yourcollection>'),
  values:   values: [
     {
       field: ["ts"]
     },
     {
       field: ["ref"]
     }
  ]
})
```

This buys you two things. Now your index will be sorted by ts (and then by ref) and you could write a range query on the timestamp as well. It also changes what your index returns, it will now return a ts and a ref. You now have the choice to either add all data you want ( which is less flexible if your data changes ) or return the ref as an extra parameter and use Map/Get as you are already doing to get the actual object. You'll have to rewrite your query only slightly:

```
await client.query(
    q.Map(
        q.Paginate(
    q.Match(q.Index("all_school_queries_by_ts")),

            {size:1000}
        ),
        q.Lambda(
            ["ts", "ref"],       // we now have two parameters
            q.Get(q.Var("ref"))  // and only use the ref, but the result will be automatically sorted by ts
        )
    )
)
```

fyi, if you prefer using the UI to create indexes, this is how it looks:

[image]

Comment: Awesome man, that worked, I saw examples using fields from data, but didn't know you could actually use the ts as the sorting parameter, thank you!!!!